# WPF YesNo Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bit field in my table that I need to convert to a Yes or No as related to a 1 or a 0.
Im using a converter like this so far and its not quite working.

Since I am binding to a combobox I need to populate it in code but then there isn't a field to set the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath to.

Also, my debugger.break() isnt working either.

Thanks for any help

```
public class BooleanToYesNoConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     Debugger.Break();
     if (value == null)
        return "No";

     bool inValue = (bool)value;
     string outValue = inValue ? "Yes" : "No";
     return outValue;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     Debugger.Break();
     if (value == null)
        return 0;

     int? outValue;
     string inValue = (string)value;

     inValue = inValue.Trim();

     if (inValue == "Yes")
     {
        outValue = 1;
     }
     else
        if (inValue == "No")
        {
           outValue = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
     return outValue;
  }
```

}

And this is my property in my ViewModel that its bound to

```
private BindableCollection<string> _licensedBitDisplay;
public BindableCollection<string> LicensedBitDisplay
{
   get { return _licensedBitDisplay; }
   set { SetValueAndNotify(() => LicensedBitDisplay, ref _licensedBitDisplay, value); }
}
```

and code populating the dropdown

```
LicensedBitDisplay = new BindableCollection<string>();
LicensedBitDisplay.AddRange(new List<string>() { "No", "Yes" });
```

Finally the xaml

```
<ComboBox Margin="24,3,0,3" Width="162" HorizontalAlignment="left" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office_Blue" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LicensedBitDisplay}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentEntity.Licensed, Mode=TwoWay, 
    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToYesNoConverter1},
    diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

Comment: So.. what's the problem?

Comment: why are you returning an object instead of a string?  Also it doesn't look like you are using the other parameters in `Convert` and `ConvertBack`, why pass them in?

Comment: Avoid yourself any more trouble and use an `ItemTemplate` for the ComboBox.

Comment: @Jonesy: Because that's how `IValueConverter` is defined

Comment: @Jonesy Your questions are invalid and is not related to what the OP is trying to do. It does not matter if he didn't use the other parameters in Convert and ConvertBack.

Comment: So I'm confused, is your original value actually a `bool` or is it some numeric value? Because in `Convert` you seem to be expecting a bool, but in `ConvertBack` you seem to want to return an `int`.

Comment: Do you want to display the Drop down as 1 and 0 and when they select a value you convert them to "Yes","No"?

Comment: Sorry I had reverted to a 0/1 loading in the dropdown during my debugging efforts. Its actually a string Yes/No. When I make a change in the dropdown it doesnt display the change and Im getting errors in teh debug trace window...

Comment: I have the converter in a assets resource xaml file so it is being properly called as we use this structure throughout our app

I want to display a "Yes" "No" in my dropdown and have it relate to the db as a 1 or 0. Im updating my posted code ...

Comment: @RobDog888 I've never seen a converter used like this, so I'm not sure it is possible, however an easy fix could be to just make a read-only that does the conversion for you, then bind to it instead.

Comment: My diag trace output

Warning: BindingExpression:   At level 1 - for State.Licensed found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Licensed)
Warning: BindingExpression: Replace item at level 1 with State (hash=11162975), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Licensed)
Warning: BindingExpression: GetValue at level 1 from State (hash=11162975) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Licensed): 'True'
Warning: BindingExpression: TransferValue - got raw value 'True'
Warning: BindingExpression: TransferValue - user's converter produced 'Visible'
Warning: BindingExpression: TransferValue - using final value 'Visible'

Answer (score 4):

Your conversion is backwards, because the binding source (`LicensedBitDisplay`) contains strings.

**Convert** converts from source to target. Source is the ViewModel, target is the UI control binding to it).
**ConvertBack** converts from target to source. This is generally only useful when you have a control accepting user input (e.g. user types "Yes" in a textbox and the converter gives `1` to the ViewModel property).

To make this work, `LicensedBitDisplay` should be a collection of `int?`. Also, your current implementation of `Convert` will fail because `int?` can't be cast to `bool`. Instead you can use [System.Convert.ToBoolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd.aspx) (which will also convert `null` to `false` automatically). The converter should be used for display only, in the ComboBox's ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LicensedBitDisplay}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentEntity.Licensed}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToYesNoConverter1}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Personally, I don't like using converters at all, especially for choosing content. Another way to express this would be through a trigger:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LicensedBitDisplay}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentEntity.Licensed}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="TextBlock" Text="No" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="1">
                    <Setter TargetName="TextBlock" Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I make LicensedBitDisplay a nullable int type then I have to populate it with integers. But then I need the dropdown to display a Yes/No instead?.

So I would need to put a converert call on the Itemsource? When I do this the dropdown gets wiped out and does not populate. I did make the casting change to the converter

Comment: I debugged the Entity at loading and the Licensed field is a "true".

Comment: @RobDog888 Actually, the converter would need to be in the ItemTemplate. I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried the updated code and couldnt get either version to work. I trried the converter example and your inline example. I get this error with inline and the entity doesnt get the dirty flag - "Cannot convert '0' from type 'Int32' to type 'System.Boolean' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding..."

Comment: @RobDog888 If the Licensed property is boolean, you can just use "True" instead of "1".

Comment: its a bit field in the database.

Comment: @RobDog888 What it gets mapped to in the database doesn't matter -- the question is what type is the Licensed property of CurrentEntity's class. Your error indicates that it's bool, so the element type of the ItemsSource collection and the DataTrigger value should both be bool.

Comment: Yup, EF mapps it as a bool property. Let me update my code changes and test. Thanks

Comment: Getting alot closer. Looks like Im getting a converter error now where it gets the True and converts it to "No". Otherwise the dropdown is populated correctly and when going from yes to no it does get marked as dirty and updates but when going any other direction it fails as below.

System.Windows.Data Warning: 90 : BindingExpression (hash=56272369): Update - got raw value 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 92 : BindingExpression (hash=56272369): Update - user's converter produced 'False'

Comment: On the ConvertBack method I'm getting a boolean instead of the string "Yes" or "No". :(

Comment: WOOT! Found the final issue. I had the converter call on both the selectedValue as well as the TextBlock. Removed it from SelectedValue and it works completely correct now! Thank You!!!